# Accessing Undeclared Variables of a Java Scipt Object

Tags: javascript, variables, object, scope

I was playing with variables, when i encountered this. I could not find out a reason for this. I want to understand this.

Below gives an exception for reference error which is obvious:

```js
console.log(age);
```

but when the same thing is done on an object, it does not throw any kind of error. It prints out 'undefined' as if the variable is already declared:

```js
var person = {};
console.log(person.age)
```

And interestingly when you check the  'person' object, there is no 'age' property.

I understand we can create property on objects directly like this:

```
person.age = 3;
```

and so can be done for global or local variables:

```
a = 3
```

But still, accessing something before assigning or declaring should throw an exception or error just like it happens in case of global or local scope variables.

Comment: strict mode prevents  the "a = 3" global  decleration

Comment: *"But still, accessing something before assigning or declaring **should** throw an exception or error just like it happens in case of global or local scope variables."* - Well, "should" is a matter of opinion. And for a lot of operations on objects it is convenient that it *doesn't* throw an error, instead returning `undefined`.

Comment: @ Volkan Seçkin Akbayır : Yes, I'm aware of that. I am asking something different.

Answer (score 1):

> Below gives an exception for reference error which is obvious

Yes, because there is no reference `age`.

> but when the same thing is done on an object, it does not throw any
>   kind of error.

Why would it? You're referencing an object through valid reference `person`, and since this object doesn't have the property `age` the value `undefined` is returned.

Comment: but 'age' variable does not exist anywhere .

Comment: what do you mean? when you're writing like this `person.age`, `age` is not a variable/reference. `person` is variable/reference, while `age` can be written like this `person['age']`, which shows that it's a string now

Comment: What i mean is that we didn't define any property called 'age' in 'person' object. And if the property is not defined how is 'person.age' a valid reference? And No writing it as person['age'] does not make it a string. This is one of a way you are accessing the property of person object by bracket notation. What i'm understanding from your response is that the properties inside an object are not treated the way as we treat variables. Is it?

Comment: @pragun, according to the spec, property names are always strings - read [this](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation). _the properties inside an object are not treated the way as we treat variables_ - that's correct

Comment: Thanks. It really clears my misconception about the properties of an object.